# How to grab the content of randomly intermingled inputs and paragraphs

Tags: jquery, html, forms, pug

Let's say I have some HTML like this:

BEWARE! It's in [Jade](http://jade-lang.com/)

```
   p Dear Lorem ipsum,                                                  
   p Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting 
      input(type="text", placeholder="phone/mail")                          
      | on [HERE]                                                           
      input(type="text", placeholder="date")                                
      | and identified the debt as [HERE]                                   
      input(type="text", placeholder="lorem")      
      | . bled it to make a type specimen book. It has survived not only five centuries, but also the leap into.                                                                       
   p  dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknow
      input(type="text", placeholder="mediums of communication", value="Messaging Service")
      | den-Sydney College in Virginia, looked up one of the more obscure Latin words, consectetur, from a Lorem Ipsum passage, and going through the cites 
   p Thank you for your cooperation.                                       

   p Sincerely,
   button#send(value="submit")
```

How would I, on $("#send").click, collect all the paragraphs so that the inputs are slipped nicely in there.

For example, I would like to know how to write a function that takes all above as input, and outputs:

```
[
   "Dear Lorem ipsum,",
   "Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting 555-1234 on [HERE] some date and identified the debt as [HERE] this is inputted text. bled it to make a type specimen book. It has survived not only five centuries, but also the leap into.",
   "dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknow this is an inputted medium of communication den-Sydney College in Virginia, looked up one of the more obscure Latin words, consectetur, from a Lorem Ipsum passage, and going through the cites",
   "Thank you for your cooperation.",
   "Sincerely"
]
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would do this: http://jsfiddle.net/b64aq/1/

Provided you're using the following HTML (which I think is the output of your Jade script):

```
<div class="container">
    <p>Dear Lorem ipsum,</p>                                               
    <p>Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting <input type="text" name="contact" placeholder="phone/mail" /> on [HERE] <input type="text" name="date" placeholder="date" /> and identified the debt as [HERE] <input type="text" name="lorem" placeholder="lorem" /> . bled it to make a type specimen book. It has survived not only five centuries, but also the leap into.</p>                                                     
    <p>dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknow <input  type="text" name="mediums" placeholder="mediums of communication"  value="Messaging Service"> den-Sydney College in Virginia, looked up one of the more obscure Latin words, consectetur, from a Lorem Ipsum passage, and going through the cites </p>
    <p>Thank you for your cooperation.</p>     
    <p>Sincerely</p>
    <button id="send" type="send" value="submit">
</div>
<div class="result"></div>
```

This should do it:

```
$('#send').click( function() {
    var array = [];
    var $paragraphs = $('.container').clone().find('p');
    $paragraphs.each( function( ) {
        $(this).children().each(function( ) {
            $(this).replaceWith( $(this).val() );
        } );
        array.push( $(this).text() );
    } );

    $('.result').append( array.join('<br>') );
} );
```

That is, first replace each input element with its value, then extract each paragraph's text.

Answer (score 1):

What about using following jQuery code:

```
$("#send").click(function(){
    var array = 
        $.map($('p'), 
        function(p){ 
            var contents = $.map($(p).contents(), 
                function(e){ 
                    if(e.nodeType === 1) return $(e).val(); 
                    if(e.nodeType === 3) return $(e).text();
                    // otherwise undefined value will be returned
                }); 

            // .join(' ') can be used to have to have some gaps between input and text
            return contents.join('');
        });
})
```

`$.map` will convert (map) all `p` elements to its text values.

As noticed by *@roobeedeedada*, jQuery `text()` does not return content of input elements, so `contents()` has been used on each `p` element and then `element.val()` or `element.text()` depending on the element type (input (`ELEMENT_NODE` - 1) or text (`TEXT_NODE` - 3) respectively).

Once you get an array of strings, you will be able to perform further modifications (e.g. using regular expressions etc.)

**A few useful links:**

- jQuery [map](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.map/)
- jQuery [text()](http://api.jquery.com/text/)
- jQuery [contents()](http://api.jquery.com/contents/)

I hope that will help.

Comment: jQuery.text() won't return the values of the input boxes, as far as I can tell: http://jsfiddle.net/6saEr/

Comment: @roobeedeedada, thanks for spotting the issue in my first approach; good solution though (+1)

Comment: I only spotted it because I'd done the exact same thing at first; I was still editing my answer's format when I saw your post :) Thanks for the +1!